# how to set circle shape of rectangle sprite in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have images in rectangle shape. When I use them in `CCSprite`, they are displayed as in Rectangle shape. But I want to change the shape of rectangle to circle and that circle image should be set in to another circle sprite. As displayed below.

[image]

Here, chicken original image is in rectangle shape and another chicken border image is circle. I want that chicken original image to be displayed in circle shape and after fit in to chicken border image that's circle.

i also check [link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/ccsprite-with-no-real-image-circle-instead-of-a-rect/)

Comment: Why does the sprite's shape matter as long as you have transparent color outside of your chicken? It might help to show us the different images and why it doesn't work as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use box2d with cocos2d.
please check the link blow:
http://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2011/06/16/using-texturepacker-and-physicseditor-together

Comment: you will need to add all resources in physics.plist other than this there is no way to do this. or you can do image processing for this. But This is not also a good way, this will eat your all memory and processing